# How do i deny access to a directory on my webserver

Tags: .htaccess, web, directory, webserver

Im trying to deny access to a directory on my webserver but allow access to a certain URL like this. Deny access to www.mydomain.com/admin but allow access to www.mydomain.com/admin/webmailogin.

I need some help. Is it possible to do this with a .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this rule in `/admin/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /admin/

RewriteRule ^$ - [F]
```